# Finding the order of two functions using the limit rule.

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I have two functions:

$f(n) = n^a$ with $a \in N$ and $a > 1$

$g(n) = 2^{\sqrt{ln(n)}}$.

I'm asked to see whenever or not $O(f(n)) \in O(g(n))$ or vice versa or if equal to each other.

To do this we can use the limit rule which states that
If you have :

1. $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {f\left( n\right) }{g\left( n\right) }=0$   then it  means that $O(f(n)) \in O(g(n))$.
2. $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {f\left( n\right) }{g\left( n\right) }=+\infty$ then it means that $O(g(n)) \in O(f(n))$
3. $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {f\left( n\right) }{g\left( n\right) }=c$ and $c \in(0, +\infty)$ then it means that $O(g(n)) = O(f(n))$, $\Theta (f(n)) = \Theta (g(n))$

Considering the above I try to do:

$\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {n^a}{2^{\sqrt{ln(n)}}}$

1. It seems obvious that $n^a$ is trending towards $\infty$ because $a>1$.
2. It seems also obvious that $ln(n)$ is trending towards $\infty$ aswell which implies that we have $2^\infty$. However I'm not so sure about $2^\infty$ trending towards $\infty$ it resembles $1^\infty$ which is a known case of indetermination.
3. If we assume that $\dfrac{1}{2^\infty} = \dfrac{1}{\infty}$ then what happens to the overall function $\dfrac {n^a}{2^{\sqrt{ln(n)}}}$.
4. Using the Hospital rule doesn't seem to be the right choice because it seems to give complicated derivatives.

How do I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is take the natural log of the limit, evaluate and then exponentiate your answer to get the limit. See this post: [Evaluating limit using logarithms.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/666626)

Comment: This is a good comment, but please don't make it into an answer post.